# How to force Python to show all computations without using print?

Tags: python

I'm used to using `Matlab`. Matlab prints all calculi you write in a script unless you finish the command with semicolon.
Is there a way to make Python show all calculi matlab-like?
I'm building a 4D matrix and i want to check my code is not failing. I cant show a 4D matrix so I want to see only some elements.
It's an annoyance to write print(matrix[1,2,1,2]) and others if I want to check a matrix is correctly build.
In matlab i'd write in my following code

```
matrix(1,2,1,2)
```

and the result would appear in screen.

Comment: how are you running your script? via command line? or in jupyter?

Comment: You might be able to do something a little like that with [`sys.settrace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the debugger [birdseye](https://birdseye.readthedocs.io/) to let you view the values of all expressions in your code as it runs. I'm the author.

There's also [icecream](https://github.com/gruns/icecream) and [q](https://github.com/zestyping/q).

A no-dependency solution is to add a utility function like:

```
def prn(x):
    print(x)
    return x
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
a = 2
b = 3
c = prn(prn(a) * prn(b))
```

And the output is:

```
2
3
6
```